# SQL count of related products via foreign key

Tags: sql

We need to build a tree view with the group structure and a count of all the products that fit into each level below it like:

```
1 - Drink related (120)
> 11 - Plastic Cups (70)
  > 111 - Vending Machine Cups (20)
     > 1111 - Vending Machine Cups 100-150cc (12)
        o Cup 1
        o Cup 2
        etc..
  > 112 - Party Cups (25)
  > 113 - Childrens Cups (25)
> 12 - Paper Cups (50)
2 - Food related (198)
> 21 - Plastic Plates (75)
etc...
```

So, we have two tables. One holds products, one holds a group structure for the products. Each product row contains only a direct foreign key link to the ID of the group row it belongs to, so for example Product ID 42231 has a reference to Group ID 4 as it is a clear plastic cup of a certain size.  A product can fit in at any group level, it won't necessarily be always at the 4th group level if it doesn't fit a specific category. (So, for example, a new line of a drink cup may be dumped in Group ID 1 "Drink Related" until it eventually gets its own category some months later.)

The group table (currently) has 1800 rows and basically forms a category tree. Each group ID is alphanumeric as some groups have too many variants to work with just numbers so:

```
ID     Gp1     Gp2     Gp3     Gp4     Desc
1      1       0       0       0       Drink Related
2      1       11      0       0       Plastic Cups
3      1       11      111     0       Vending machine cups
4      1       11      111     1111    Vending machine cups 100-150cc
```

If I only wanted to show the exact number of products in each ID, I could do something like this:

```
select *,
(select count(1) 
    from products
    where groupID=g.id and isDeleted=0) 
    as groupProductCount
 from groups g
 order by g.group1, g.group2, g.group3, g.group4
```

...but I'm after a more recursive count where it shows the count for all products below the current level so at a glance I can see there are 120 drink-related products within group 1 and not 3 which are directly in *group ID* 1 at the moment.

Personally I think I'm going to have to get the DBA to add in the 4 group levels to the product record too as otherwise for each record in the group table I'd have to determine which level we're at (zeros in unused level, so a zero in group 4 means we're at level 3, zero in group 3 means we're at level 2, etc) and then scan through every product record (currently 10,000 and growing) to see if the group it falls in (read via the foreign key group ID) has a level that matches the current group level record I'm trying to count for.

I can't see that this can be achieved efficiently with just the group ID in the product record. Am I right here or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force solution. (I assume SqlServer but it shouldn't be difficult to port to others).

```
WITH LeafGroup AS (
    SELECT Id
          ,CASE WHEN Gp4 <> '0' 
                THEN Gp4
                ELSE CASE WHEN Gp3 <> '0'
                          THEN Gp3
                          ELSE CASE WHEN Gp2 <> '0'
                                    THEN Gp2
                                    ELSE Gp1
                               END
                     END
           END AS GroupId
    FROM Groups
)
-- Build a delimited string from the groups
,DelimitedGroups AS (
    SELECT Id
          ,Gp1 + '|' + 
           CASE WHEN Gp2 = '0' THEN '' ELSE Gp2 + '|' END +
           CASE WHEN Gp3 = '0' THEN '' ELSE Gp3 + '|' END + 
           CASE WHEN Gp4 = '0' THEN '' ELSE Gp4 + '|' END AS Delim
    FROM Groups
)
-- Find ids where the delimited string starts with the same groups
,ConnectedGroups AS (
    SELECT DG1.Id AS TopId
         , DG2.Id AS ConnectedId
    FROM DelimitedGroups DG1
         INNER JOIN DelimitedGroups DG2
             ON LEFT(DG2.Delim, LEN(DG1.Delim)) = DG1.Delim
)
-- Now we can fetch all groups for each Id
,GroupsPerId AS (
    SELECT ConnectedGroups.TopId AS Id
          ,LeafGroup.GroupId
    FROM ConnectedGroups
         INNER JOIN LeafGroup
             ON ConnectedGroups.ConnectedId = LeafGroup.Id
)
-- Count all products for each id
SELECT GroupsPerId.Id
      ,COUNT(1)
FROM GroupsPerId
     LEFT JOIN Products
         ON GroupsPerId.GroupId = Products.GroupId
GROUP BY GroupsPerId.Id
```

Comment: Looks complex!  I just tried it and got: `Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '29b1' to data type int`Remember that I mentioned the groups aren't numeric, some of them are alphanumeric (as seen above). I can't quite see what's causing the SQL engine to bork out with the "int" problem...?

Comment: Got it to work by changing second last line to `convert(varchar,GroupsPerId.GroupId) = convert(varchar,Products.GroupId)`  It has a heavy 61% usage spike in execution plan doing a nested loop/inner join but I imagine that's why you called it a "brute force" solution?  What can I say, it works! Thankyou, this is utterly beyond my SQL capabilities to envisage but after deconstructing what you did I can understand the logic behind it now.  Is there any way I could make this more efficient?

Comment: Actually I don't think it's getting the product count right, I'm just checking it now.